# VirtualBox installation produces "codec overrun" error

Tags: virtualbox, osx-leopard

I can't find any information on this:  I downloaded the VirtualBox DMG for Intel Mac multiple times, but when I click the DMG to install, it fails to mount "due to codec overrun."

My Operating System is:  MacOS/x v10.5

What's the deal?

Comment: @randalf: that edit is pretty hilarious, sorry to make you capitalize so many things. I just type faster that way so it seems more logical to me. Oh, and i meant to say "what the deal" to express a colloquial phrase implying both my frustration and confusion toward the topic. And technically we shouldnt be using contractions either.

Comment: for posterity's sake, yes it was SPI turned on in router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea, but I googled it and found this:
http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-25005.html

> Sorry to bring up an old thread, but
>   as its googles top hit for "codec
>   overrun" I thought I would, for
>   informational sake, chime in with my
>   solution.
>
> I recently had this issue, lots of
>   downloads having Codec Overruns.
>
> After much reasearch it turned out to
>   be caused by the SPI Firewall thats
>   built into my router. It was throwing
>   away bits of information it didnt
>   like, and corrupting files. Since
>   turning it off everything has been
>   perfect.

Comment: yeah i think it might be something along these lines, i am on a network of a relative who didnt set it up for themselves. I DL'ed a couple files and checked their md5 and it was incorrect.